# See download progress with this php download script?

Tags: php

I'm using this script to download files and it works, but I don't get any download progress in % or time in my browser, it just says unknown. Is it possible to tweak the code to add that parameter? And apart from that, do you guys see any other weird things in the code or anything that can be improved? Thanks!

```
<?php

$filepath = 'x';
$title = 'y';
$download = true;

header("Cache-control: private");

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

if ($download) {
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $title . "\"");
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
} else {
       header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $title . "\"");
}

// Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

readfile($filepath);

exit;

?>
```

Comment: No, can't be done in PHP. Maybe with Jquery or ajax. But php only renders a html file.

Comment: I don't think this is really a question. Maybe move this to code review?

Comment: @Andreas Aha ok. So I gain that I can protect the URL, but I loose the progress indication (which I would see if I didn't go through the script). So you think that a client side script can access that information anyway?

Comment: @ateesdalejr By Code Review's standard, the code isn't working correctly as intended, and would therefore be off-topic there.

Comment: @200_success Oh, didn't know that. From what the OP said I assumed the code was functional.

Answer (score 0):

The server is not sending a Content-Length header, so the client cannot know how much more data to expect, and cannot display the progress.  If the response consists of the contents of a file, you can obtain the file size by calling [`stat($filepath)`](https://secure.php.net/stat).

Comment: You may wish to show how to set the content length header...  such as `header("Content-length: ".filesize($filepath));`

Comment: Thank you. makes sense. So there is no other way around it?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks. I tried the header() but it gave me "0 bytes" and didn't download the file.

Comment: If you have `$filepath = 'x';` I'm not surprised. Or if that is just for the purpose of the question, make sure you path is correct.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes, it's just an example. The path works. Adding `header("Content-length: ".filesize($filepath));` did not.